# Rendering text in Canvas at a specific frame?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to learn how to use canvas in order to create the effect of the Apple Airpods page. I've been following a tutorial which shows how to do the animation of the different images, making each frame correspond to scrolling. My question is, how would you add text inbetween the frames? For example between frame 50-100 a text should appear in the middle of the screen, and disappear after frame 100 has passed. My initial thought was an if-statement, that triggered it when the framecount was between the two values. It works, but it places the text at the top of the document. I cannot seem to find any information on how to render it through the canvas. I am very new to canvas, so I hope you will bear over with me!

The code in question:

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.querySelector('.airpods-scrolling');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

// index is the number we will be incrementing. index.toString = makes it from a number to a string, so it can be parsed. padStart = adds 4x0 om front of the number.
const currentFrame = index => (
`https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
);

// Handling how many images / frames we have
const frameCount = 147;

// Canvas height and width, same as image
canvas.height = 770;
canvas.width = 1158;
// Generating a new image.
const img = new Image();
// To add to dom put inside ()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
img.onload = function(){
// Drawing image inside canvas - 0, 0 is X and Y coords
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Function that updates the image
const updateImage = index => {
    // Passing index so it can update the image
    img.src = currentFrame(index);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

// Handling changes when scrolling. Everytime we scroll this function is triggering
window.addEventListener('scroll', () =>{
    // Variable to get the scroll top value
    const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
    // Adding maximum value a user can scroll to
    const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    // Handling progress when scrolling
    const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
    // Handling frame counting
    const frameIndex = Math.min(frameCount - 1, Math.floor(scrollFraction * frameCount));
    // Rendering the images over and over - using the updateImage function from earlier to refresh the rendering of canvas
    requestAnimationFrame( () => updateImage(frameIndex + 1));
});
```

```css
html{
height: 100vh;
}

body{
background: #000;
height: 400vh;
}

canvas{
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
max-height: 100vh;
max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Image Scrolling Animation</title>
</head>
<body>

    <canvas class="airpods-scrolling"></canvas>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you had two places with `drawImage`, not quite sure why you are doing that, so I removed one and added the `fillText` to render the text...

If you need read more about fillText here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text

I'm rendering two words, but the second is behind an if-statement to only render
`if (frameIndex > 5)` you can change that to anything you need.

See working code below

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.querySelector('.airpods-scrolling');
canvas.height = 770;
canvas.width = 1158;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.shadowColor = "white";
context.shadowBlur = 4;

const currentFrame = index => (
  `https://www.apple.com/105/media/us/airpods-pro/2019/1299e2f5_9206_4470_b28e_08307a42f19b/anim/sequence/large/01-hero-lightpass/${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.jpg`
);

const frameCount = 147;
var frameIndex = 0

const img = new Image();
img.src = currentFrame(1);
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  context.font = "178px serif";
  context.fillText("Hello", 90, 160);
  if (frameIndex > 5) {
    context.font = "220px serif";
    context.fillText("World", 99, 320);
  }
}

const updateImage = index => {
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollFraction = html.scrollTop / (html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
  frameIndex = Math.min(frameCount - 1, Math.floor(scrollFraction * frameCount));
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1));
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  height: 400vh;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="airpods-scrolling"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, cool to know how you pull it off through canvas. I've been working on a way to pull it off with a separate script, as to actually "render" text in the DOM (for SEO purposes etc.) - I suppose that way would be prefered?